# Laravel: Handling Laravel API URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-api

I have API which I have uploaded on the server.
The url looks like this:
`api.subdomain.domain.com/`
I've made .htaccess to go directly to the public
but when accessing it should be like this:
`api.subdomain.domain.com/api/login`

How can I access it directly like `api.subdomain.domain.com/login`.

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've tried adding `/api`, but when accessing the URL that I want it displays a 404 error

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open RouteServiceProvider.php. Depending on which version of Laravel you are using find function map{Route File: web.php/api.php/any custom file}Routes() (if the version is older than Laravel 8), otherwise you will see and add a prefix to your route file. Like[image]

Comment: Can you show your route file? Maybe you are using laravel's default authentication?